# OLED screen brightness doesn't work - Samsung Galaxy Book

Tags: ubuntu, arch-linux

I just bought a Samsung Galaxy Book 2 from Best Buy and installed Arch + KDE on it. The screen brightness controls don't change the screen brightness at all and after searching around on the internet I found that it's because of the OLED screen. I then installed Ubuntu thinking maybe it had a patch for it, but same problem. I tried `oled-linux` and `xrandr` but neither work. What do I do? Is there any solution? I've been working on this for an hour now.

Answer (score 2):

I spent too much time to battle with this problem of controlling  the brightness on "Samsung galaxy pro 2". No solution that use xrandr can work. The problem is upstream!

The problem is coming from the video driver (intel i915). By default, the i915 driver tries to use PWM to control backlight brightness, which does not work.

One good solution is to pass the kernel the following argument to indicate how to access the backlight control. We can do this with grub:

---

ON ARCH (transpose with your own linux flavor)

1. Modify the GRUB config file
   `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
   in the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT
   append "i915.enable_dpcd_backlight=3"
   then save the file
2. Rebuild GRUB for it can take the change of your config file, by doing (on Arch)
   `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`
3. reboot and test with the key if it works

Now you understand you are better in linux, for me that's the Linux Philosophy.
sources :
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Backlight#Unable_to_control_eDP_Panel_brightness_(Intel_i915_only)

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same issue on my Galaxy Book2 360 with Fedora 36, and this Gnome extension seems to help (not sure what the KDE equivalent would be):
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1625/soft-brightness/

Apparently there is also a way in the bootloader settings to solve the issue (at least on other laptops), but Samsung uses their own GUI for the bootloader and I can't find the option necessary.

Hopefully, the next kernel update should solve some of the issues and allow us to natively do it without the need for a Gnome extension

Answer (score 1):

I am running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS on my galaxy book2 pro 360 with only two issues - keyboard backlight and fingerprint sensor not working. I had to switch to mainline kernel (5.16 before and 6.0 now) to get sound and full CPU support. I followed some of [these](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/howto-set-up-the-audio-card-in-samsung-galaxy-book/37090) instructions to try to get the sound working unsuccessfully before upgrading to mainline kernel. I think it was the combination of the settings from the manjaro link and the new mainline kernel that got my sound working.